FAF: Lightning Bolt vs Maltese Cross on approach plates?
Here is my understanding (please correct me if I am wrong):
A maltese cross is a FAF indicated with a distance and lightning bolt is FAF indicated by interception of glide slope. Non precision approaches like LOC, LNAV FAF is indicated by Maltese cross and ILS FAF is indicated by lightning cross.
However, what isn't clear to me is whether LPV and LNAV/VNAV approaches should use glideslope intercept or distance to indicate FAF?  Is this a DA vs MDA question?

The final approach fix on both LNAV/VNAV and LPV approaches is at glideslope intercept. The Maltese cross is only for non-precision approaches like LNAV or LOC.

LPV and LNAV/VNAV are officially "Approaches with Vertical Guidance" because they don't meet one (completely irrelevant) detail in ICAO's definition of "Precision Approach".
However, they have a DA, so for all practical purposes, you treat them as if they were Precision--and that means using the lightning bolt rather than the Maltese cross.

This is the answer I was looking for. If it has a DA, then lightning bolt. MDA is Maltese cross.

To expand on Chris' answer:
The Maltese cross designates the non-precision final approach fix. It may be a DME fix, intersection fix, or waypoint. The important point is that this is an identifiable fix, not just a distance.
The lightning bolt designates the glideslope/glidepath (ILS/MLS/TLS approach or RNAV, respectively) intercept point. On conventional procedures (i.e., those with a glideslope), the lightning bolt does not have to be colocated with a fix/waypoint. The actual glideslope altitude will be indicated in a smaller type size breaking the vertical component line.
On an RNAV procedure with vertical guidance, the lightning bolt will be located at a waypoint. This serves as the precision final approach fix (with "precision" meaning the approach has vertical guidance, not the ICAO definition of a precision approach). These approaches also use the smaller type size breaking the vertical component line. However, this value on a US TERPS procedure will be the same as the restrictive crossing altitude for that same waypoint.
The distant between components of the procedure is indicated in the baseline and is given to the nearest tenth of a nautical mile. This information is for advisory use only.
